# Need help in getting list of IP address with Name, Status, State, OSversion, Nodename against each VM

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, hyper-v

I need help with script. Below is my script for pulling data from Hyper v nodes. I want some VM attributes as well in output. But I am getting blank. Can someone pls help to understand what is wrong and how to fix this. All the properties which I want are not there in $Vms. How to combine properties from $VirtualM and $VMs and get an output.

```
$Nodes = Get-Content -Path "C:\Nodes.txt"

foreach($Node in $Nodes)
          {

 $VMs = Get-VM | Get-VMNetworkAdapter | Select-Object -Property VMName, IPAddresses
 $VirtualM = Get-VM | Select Name, Status, State
 $Output = @()

 foreach($VM in $VMs)
    {
   $results = [ordered]@{

        'NodeName' = $Node;    
        'VMName' = $VM.VMName; 
        'IPaddress' = $VM.IPAddresses[0];
        }
$Output += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $results
$Output += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $VirtualM
    } 
} Write-Output $Output | Select-Object -Property NodeName, VMName, IPAddress, State, Status


Output is as below
=========================

Output Comes Like Below

NodeName  : ABC
VMName    : s1
IPaddress : 192.168.1.5
State     : 
Status    : 

NodeName  : ABC
VMName    : s2
IPaddress : 192.168.1.6
State     : 
Status    : 

NodeName  : ABC
VMName    : s3
IPaddress : 192.168.1.7
State     : 
Status    : 

NodeName  : DEF
VMName    : D1
IPaddress : 192.168.1.9
State     : 
Status    : 

NodeName  : DEF
VMName    : D2
IPaddress : 192.168.1.10
State     : 
Status    :
```

Comment: foreach($Node in $Nodes)
          {
 $VMs = Get-VM | Get-VMNetworkAdapter | Select-Object -Property VMName, IPAddresses
 $VirtualM = Get-VM | Select Name, Status, State
 $Output = @()
 foreach($VM in $VMs)
    {
   $results = [ordered]@{
        'NodeName' = $Node;    
        'VMName' = $VM.VMName; 
        'IPaddress' = $VM.IPAddresses[0];
        }
$Output += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $results
$Output += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $VirtualM
    } 
} Write-Output $Output | Select-Object -Property NodeName, VMName, IPAddress, State, Status

Comment: =============================
Output Comes Like Below
=================================
NodeName  : ABC
VMName    : s1
IPaddress : 192.168.1.5
State     : 
Status    : 

NodeName  : ABC
VMName    : s2
IPaddress : 192.168.1.6
State     : 
Status    : 

NodeName  : ABC
VMName    : s3
IPaddress : 192.168.1.7
State     : 
Status    :

Comment: Please [edit] your question to contain additional information, especially code is hard to read due to missing line breaks.

Comment: Thanks a lot LotPings. Yes, I understand and I apologize for the same. I am new to power shell and this is the first time I have created a question on an online forum. Somehow it was not allowing me to save the contents(throwing error) of my code while I was creating original question. I have edited it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Update

Adding a `try{}catch{}` to see where the object fails, if it does.
Back to your question, you can add multiple properties from different variables in to an object *(like in the example bellow `$VM.Name` , `$VM.Name` and `$Node`)* .

Selecting before the end results is bad practice. You also do not need to run the same command twice, you can instead "utilize" what you already have ran. If you are making an object, you can put all the collective input in there from different variables and there you can specify what you need. You are also resetting the `$Output` after every `$Node`, you want to put the array outside and pump it with objects. I have never used the VM cmdlets, so I just rebuild your script without testing it.

```
$Output = @()

foreach($Node in $Nodes) {
    $VMs = Get-VM 
    foreach($VM in $VMs) {
        $VMName = Get-VMNetworkAdapter -VMName $VM.Name
        try{
            $CombineObject= New-Object -type PSObject -Property  @{ 
                NodeName  = $Node ;
                VMName    = $VMName.VMName ;
                IPaddress = $VMName.IPAddresses ;
                Name      = $VM.Name ;
                Status    = $VM.Status ;
                State     = $VM.State
            }
        }catch{
            Write-Output "Error occure with either: $Node or $($VM.Name) or $($VMName.VMName)"
        }
        $Output += $CombineObject
    } 
} 
#Display the array of objects
$Output
```

Since this is not tested, you should test the two cmdlets separately to make sure you get the right input/output

Answer (score 0):

When using a mutliple steps pipeline the intermediate properties are no longer available.
Better use a `ForEach` providing a separate variable name like you did with $Node.

This untested script:

```
## Q:\Test\2018\09\22\SO_52459730.ps1
$Nodes = @('ABC')
$Result = ForEach($Node in $Nodes) { 
     ForEach ($VM in (Get-VM -ComputerName $Node)){
         [PSCustomObject]@{ 
             NodeName  = $Node
             VMName    = $VM.VMName
             IPaddress = ($VM | Get-VMNetworkAdapter).IPAddresses[0]
             State     = $VM.State
             Status    = $VM.Status
          } 
     } 
} 
$Result | Format-Table -Auto
#$Result | Out-Gridview
#$Result | Export-Csv All-VMs.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Should return an output like this:

```
NodeName  VMName  IPaddress    State    Status 
--------  ------  ---------    -----    ------
ABC       s1      192.168.1.5  Running  Operating normally
ABC       s2      192.168.1.6  Running  Operating normally
ABC       s3      192.168.1.7  Running  Operating normally
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. It made my day. I have few additional queries to understand this better. The script works flawlessly and gives output. But I get below error.

Cannot index into a null array.
At line:4 char:10
+          [PSCustomObject]@{
+          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray

I researched around this to understand concept for [PSCustomObject] but did not find a good post.

Comment: Also please help me if I want to achieve the same result of IP address using Get-VM $Node | Select -ExpandProperty NetworkAdapters | Select IPaddresses , how will I go for it. I will not be able to run it inside second foreach loop as Get-VM will work on $Node. I want to understand how we can merge different properties to one array to get desired output, if that is possible.

Comment: The error you are getting is because somewhere in the object you are trying to put a `$NULL` value. I suspect this is the `IPaddress = ($VM | Get-VMNetworkAdapter).IPAddresses[0]` , the best way to find out what goes wrong is to use `try{}catch{}` , look at my example, I will edit it in a bit with a try/catch

Comment: Thanks Vasil for your Kind Inputs. Can you please help me with my second question in comment. Posting it below again.
"Also please help me if I want to achieve the same result of IP address using Get-VM $Node | Select -ExpandProperty NetworkAdapters | Select IPaddresses , how will I go for it. I will not be able to run it inside second foreach loop as Get-VM will work on $Node."

Comment: I am not really sure I understand the question, but if you are looking for a value inside another value, may be look at this example :
    `$vmNodeIP=Get-VM $Node` and then expand it
    `$vmNodeIP.NetworkAdapters.IPaddresses`, if this is what you want, you can then include that `$vmNodeIp.NetworkAdapters.IpAddresses` in the object as one extra line.

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply and resolving my query. Yes thats exactly what I asked. Have a good day ahead